# Access job parameters in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I need to dynamically get current Jenkins job parameters and then pass it to a shell script in build step. If I change one or multiple choice parameters while in Build with parameters page, then the Groovy choice parameter needs to automatically update. Is this possible?

The groovy choice calls a shell script with the current parameters from the job and will give the existing archive versions from a folder. 
e.g. ./test.sh app1 environment1 will produce 1.1.2 and 1.1.3. I need this to change accordingly if I change to app2 and environment2 from the choice parameters in build page.

If I try:

```
import hudson.model.*
def app = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("app")
```

I get an error: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding build

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, I've installed active choice plugin that did the trick.